# Django Simple History Delete all History on Model Delete

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

Using django simple history, is there a way to delete all the history associated with an object if the object itself is deleted? For example, if I have a User model:

```
User.objects.filter(id=to_delete_id).delete()
```

That query will delete that User, but it doesn't erase all the history, which I would like to save on data costs. Is there a way to automatically delete all of that specific user's history on delete, or do I have to do this:

```
User.objects.filter(id=to_delete_id).delete()
User.history.filter(id=to_delete_id).delete()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a solution, let me know if this is bad for some performance reason:

Override the delete() method on a User:

```
class User(...):
    ...
    def delete(self):
        self.history.filter().delete()
        super(User, self).delete()
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docs: https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.0/historical_model.html#deleting-historical-record

> In some circumstances you may want to delete all the historical
>   records when the master record is deleted. This can be accomplished by
>   setting `cascade_delete_history=True`

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    history = HistoricalRecords(cascade_delete_history=True)
```